# Using Infinispan hotrod python client

Tags: infinispan

I want to test how hotrod python client works. While testing i am facing an issue where i am not able to store any element whose message id in request header is 128. While checking the code of remotecache.py and **init**.py i found that HEADER_RES_FMT is set to ">BBBBB" for magic, msg_id, op_code, status and topology_mark. what i believe after going through documentation of hotrod protocol is, this format should be ">BLBBB" as datatype of message id vLong.

Also, i tried changing the format ">BLBBB", but then also it didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sonal

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the client, already reported here: https://github.com/infinispan/python-client/issues/6

`L` won't work because the message id has a variable length (1 up to 9 bytes). I don't think `struct.unpack` can handle that, so the client should read the bytes one by one.